# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 29: parser error : StartTag

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

May I have Help please

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 29: [image: parser error] : StartTag: invalid element name in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php on line 552

Comment: Have you added/updated any xml file ??

Comment: No, I haven't made any updates.
I only added a category and that gave me this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Find and Replace these lines**

```
protected function _loadXmlString($xmlString)
        {
            $unescapedValues = ['&nbsp;', '&eacute;', '&agrave;', '&ugrave;', '&egrave;', '&ocirc;', '&ndash;'];
    
    
            foreach ($unescapedValues as $value) {
                // wrap in CDATA to escape
                $xmlString = str_replace($value, "<![CDATA[$value]]>", $xmlString);
            }
    
            return simplexml_load_string($xmlString, 'Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element');
    
        }
```